# Exponential growth over rational field

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics, exponential-function, exponential-sum

A expression $a(x,h) \in \mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}$ imply that 
$$ a(x,h)^n+p_{n-1}(h)[x]a(x,h)^{n-1}+\cdots+p_0(h)[x]=0  $$

For example $e^{dh}x \notin \mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}.$ Where $d$ could be treated as constant.

I want to show the following expression does not belong $\mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}$. We treat $d$ as a constant. 
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{d}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k-1}e^{d(k-\frac{d+1}{2})h} \notin \mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}. $$
   It has an exponential in the expression and looks like the example but I still could not conclude. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the following way to answer my question but I think I am bit sloppy. 
Lets denote the expression by 
$$f(h):=\sum_{k=1}^{d}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k-1}e^{d(k-\frac{d+1}{2})h} \notin \mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}. $$
Now as $\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty} f(h)\rightarrow  \pm \infty.$ depending on $d$ being odd or even. Not only that I guess it's asymtoptically equivalent to $e^{dh}$ hence $f(h)\notin  \mathbb{C}(h)[x]^\mathrm{alg}.$